# Async/await/promises problem with MSAL.JS

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, msal.js

I'm trying to write a function to acquire the Bearer token and return the headers before calling an API on behalf of the user, using MSAL.JS.

I think I'm struggling with the await/async/promises. Stuff I'm not really familiat with, at least in JS.

This is the function (I omitted the ssoSilent/login's part):

```js
const prepareAPI = async (type) => {
    const ssoRequest = {
        loginHint: _userUpn,
        scopes: ["openid", "profile", "user.read", _APIscope]
    };
    // if the user is already logged in you can acquire a token
    if (msalInstance.getAccount()) {
        var tokenRequest = {
            scopes: [_APIscope]
        };
        try {
            const resp = await msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest);
            console.log(resp.accessToken);
            var headers = new Headers();
            var bearer = "Bearer " + resp.accessToken;
            headers.append("Authorization", bearer);
            resolve({
                method: type,
                headers: headers
            });

        } catch (err) {
            // could also check if err instance of InteractionRequiredAuthError if you can import the class.
            if (err.name === "InteractionRequiredAuthError") {
                return msalInstance.acquireTokenPopup(tokenRequest)
                    .then(response => {
                        return getOpts(response.accessToken, type);
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log("Something went wrong:" + err);
                    });
            }
        }
    } else {
        // ... RequestSSO, loginPopup, etc,
    }
};
```

I call the function like this:

```js
    prepareAPI("GET")
        .then(opts => console.log("Headers: ", opts));
```

I get the token in the console.log(resp.accessToken) just before the resolve.
But "opts" is undefined, and looks like is executed before the token retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason in your code to use anything other than async await.  Simplify the code by replacing .then with await and removing any .catch calls(It will throw instead). Make sure any async calls(resolve?) have an await statement. Keep in mind await is just syntax sugar for resolving a Promise where it returns the value on resolve or throws on reject.

Ex

```
prepareAPI("GET")
        .then(opts => console.log("Headers: ", opts))
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

becomes

```
try {
   const opts = await prepareAPI("GET");
   console.log("Headers: ", opts)
} catch (e) {console.error(e);}
```

Comment: Await only works in an async function.
That won't change the result.

Comment: That was just an example on how to update code. Simplify your code first and from there you can check for corectness.